# Using the content of a directory to create a table of a website

Tags: javascript, web

I'm currently facing the following problem: I have a directory with PDFs and I want to build a table using the information within the PDF names. For example, I have PDF that is named like so: name_topic_type.pdf. Now I would like to build a table with 3 columns and 1 row for each pdf. I know how to create the table once I have the necessary information (using JavaScript). What I don't know is how to get the information. The directory will be on the Webserver, on request of the WebSite a script should be launched that takes the content of director and makes it available for my JS file that then builds the table.

I have no backend experience, so I dont really know how to approach a problem like this, although its probably simple.

Many Thanks
Ruby

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language. You've tagged this [tag:javascript] but not said if you are using Node.js, Classic ASP, or something else. You've also named yourself after [tag:ruby-on-rails] implying that you want to do this in Ruby using the Rails framework. It really isn't clear how you're trying to do this.

Comment: Step 2: Do some basic research. Read an introductory guide to server side programming in the language of your choice. Then search how to read directory listings using that programming language.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, but the name is a pun on my forename, so thats just me trying to be funny. I know JS so NodeJs would probably be a good choice, but since the task is comparatively small, i don't care to much about the language. I just need the filenames to be accessible by my frontend JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this would depend on which backend language you plan to use and how you plan to send data to front end.

An example below is in PHP outputting json but many other options.

```
<?php
$arr = scandir('/path/to/pdfs');
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
  //extra processing to add other columns data here
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot. Since the backend portion of this task is rather small (literally just getting the pdf names), i don't care to much about the language used, but what is still unclear to me is how to get the data from the backend to my frontend JavaScript.

Comment: The language is the critical first step since you need to have that software installed on the server and it changes the code and approach to getting the data.
This code as shown will read the directory and output it as json which the frontend can read.
Your javascript can call the server via ajax to receive this data.

Comment: I did some research and modified your function to write the data to a json file. Then i used ajax to request it. works fine, thanks alot